# How to pass string value from one class to another class?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i hope this is old question , but yet i need a solution from you .
I have a class i.e public partial class form1 and i have initialized some strings here . i want to use the string values in another form . how can i do that .

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public string firstrange ="" ;
    public string firstrange1 ="";
    public string lastrange = "";
    public string lastrange1 = "";
    public string Receivedrange = "";
    public string Receivedrange1 = "";



public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
         }

// while loading form1 , i'm adding some values to the strings from CSV

 firstrange = WorksheetSourcee1.UsedRange.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString();
 firstrange1 = WorksheetSourcee1.UsedRange.Cells[1, 2].Value.ToString();
}
```

Now i want use these strings in another form2 , i just need to get the same  string values. can anybody suggest me about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use form2 constructor to get the required parameters.

```
 public Form2 (string yourParam)
 {
 InitializeComponent(); 
 }
```

And in the current form just pass those parameters:

```
Form2 = new Form2 (parameterName);
Form2 .ShowDialog();
```